# delete multiple entries while adding values in there corresponding list

Tags: python, sqlite, firefox

I have two lists final_domain(it contains lists of domain names) and final_count (it contains there corresponding hits or count). I want to sort the domain names by deleting multiple entries with corresponding increase in the hits or counts in the final_count list. 
how can i do it ?

original code :

```
import sqlite3
import os
import collections
from urlparse import urlparse
#diretory path (for windows only)

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qoupopgx.default")

final_domain=[]
final_url=[]
final_count=[]

#Fecthing urls from the firefox database

db = sqlite3.connect("places.sqlite")
urls = db.execute("SELECT url FROM moz_places").fetchall()
for url in urls:
     final_url.append(url[0])


#Converting url to domain_name

for temp in final_url:
     parsed_uri = urlparse(temp)
     domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
     final_domain.append(domain)
     #print domain


#Fecthing url count from the firefox database

count = db.execute("SELECT visit_count FROM moz_places").fetchall()
for temp1 in count:
     final_count.append(temp1[0])
     #print temp1[0]
```

In this code i am grabbing the history form the Firefox and then extracting the url and visit_count from sqlite database. I have successfully extracted domain name from the url and there visit_count . but may entries are multiple in final_domain:

```
6d6d893d.reverse.layershift.co.uk/
6d6d893d.reverse.layershift.co.uk/
6d6d893d.reverse.layershift.co.uk/
9gag.com/
9gag.com/
9gag.com/
```

they have some corresponding hits in final_count: 5,6,7,2,3,1

I have to merge them into one like:(desired output)

```
6d6d893d.reverse.layershift.co.uk/
9gag.com/
```

with corresponding hits : 18 ,6

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple rows, use aggregation.
This requires that the domain name extraction is done in SQL:

```sql
SELECT substr(url, 1, instr(substr(url, 9), '/') + 8),
       SUM(visit_count)
FROM moz_places
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: CL. From this query I can only able to fetch the urls and there visit_count with the sorted order by urls . I want to extract the domain name form the urls (which i have done in the code) then delete the multiple entries in final_domain by adding there corresponding visit_count.

Comment: You can extract the domain name from these urls, too. This returns only one row for each distinct URL, so you don't need to delete anything.

Comment: CL. I think you are not getting my question.After running your query i got this [link](http://postimg.org/image/gmxudfxjz/). But i want to collect are the http://sciencedirect.com by adding there visit_count values like (1+2+1+1.....).